# Converting Error Response Array with Retrofit2 converter

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

Whenever I get error, the error body is as follows:

```
[
 {
  "errorCode": 10001,
  "resource": null,
  "resourceId": null,
  "field": null,
  "parameter": null,
  "header": null,
  "allowedValues": null,
  "maxLength": null,
  "minLength": null
 }
]
```

The error body is an array. I have different bodies for success of many API methods, but the error array response is standardized. I tried doing many things

- making wrapper class with generic type success response and array of error response and made deserializer for that, but I can't deserialize from type variable and from paramaterized class.
- made a ErrorDeserializer but I have no idea how can I make Retrofit use it for error responses.

I could definitely just serialize raw string everytime on every callback for all my api methods, but I have so many of them, I need generalized solution. If I didn't explain myself properly, please ask.

I'll add examples of what I tried (they will be incomplete however):

Response wrap class:

```
    public class ResponseWrap<T> {
        @Nullable
        private final T response;

        @Nullable
        private final List<ErrorResponse> errorResponses;

        public ResponseWrap(@Nullable T response, @Nullable List<ErrorResponse> errorResponses) {
            this.response = response;
            this.errorResponses = errorResponses;
        }
    }
```

Error response class:

```
    public class ErrorResponse {
        private int errorCode;
        private String resource;
        private String resourceId;
        private String field;
        private String parameter;
        private String header;
        private String allowedValues;
        private int maxLength;
        private int minLength;

        // getters and setters
    }
```

Error deserializer:

```
    public class ErrorDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ArrayList<ErrorResponse>> {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<ErrorResponse> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ErrorResponse>>(){}.getType();
            ArrayList<ErrorResponse> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
            final JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

                error.setErrorCode(jsonObject.get("errorCode").getAsInt());
                error.setResource(jsonObject.get("resource").getAsString());
                error.setResourceId(jsonObject.get("resourceId").getAsString());
                error.setField(jsonObject.get("field").getAsString());
                error.setParameter(jsonObject.get("parameter").getAsString());
                error.setHeader(jsonObject.get("header").getAsString());
                error.setAllowedValues(jsonObject.get("allowedValues").getAsString());
                error.setMaxLength(jsonObject.get("maxLength").getAsInt());
                error.setMinLength(jsonObject.get("minLength").getAsInt());

                list.add(error);
             }

             return list;
        }
    }
```

Response wrap deserializer - **it's not working**, 2 errors:

- List error = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("error"), ArrayList.class); // Can't select from parameterized class
- T success = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, T.class); // Can't select from type variable

  ```
  public class ResponseWrapDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<ResponseWrap<T>> {
      @Override
      public ResponseWrap<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
          // Get JsonObject
          final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
          if (jsonObject.has("error")) {

              Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                      .registerTypeAdapter(typeOfT, new ErrorDeserializer())
                      .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                      .create();

              List<ErrorResponse> error = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("error"), ArrayList<ErrorResponse>.class);

              return new ResponseWrap<T>(null, error);
          } else {
              T success = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, T.class);
              return new ResponseWrap<T>(success, null);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

The idea was to use them all like this:

```
@POST("Login")
Call<ResponseWrap<AccessTokenResponse>> Login(@Body LoginRequest request);
```

But I can't because of above mentioned reasons.

The question is: How to process error responses in a generic way that are in an array using Retrofit2?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write `T.class` -- this is illegal in Java. In order to overcome this limitation you must either pas a `Type` instance yourself somehow or resolve generic types parameters from what Gson gives you. In the first case you'd need dozen JSON deserializers to bind various `ResponseWrap<T>` parametization; whilst in the second case can simply resolve the actual type parameter yourself. At the call site you can use `TypeToken`s -- a special Gson mechanism to define a type parameter via a type parameterization. Also note that you don't have to instantiate internal `Gson` instances: this might be relatively expensive (especially in sequence) and disrespect the `Gson` configuration the current deserializer is bound for - use `JsonDeserializationContext` since it can give you all you need (except downstream type adapters).

The following JSON deserializer uses the second approach as I find it more convenient.

```java
final class ResponseWrapJsonDeserializer<T>
        implements JsonDeserializer<ResponseWrap<T>> {

    // This deserializer holds no state, so we can hide its instantiation details away  
    private static final JsonDeserializer<ResponseWrap<Object>> responseWrapJsonDeserializer = new ResponseWrapJsonDeserializer<>();

    // Type instances from TypeToken seems to be fully immutable and can be treated as value types, thus we can make them static final to re-use (it's safe)
    private static final Type errorResponseListType = new TypeToken<List<ErrorResponse>>() {
    }.getType();

    private ResponseWrapJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    // Just cheating the call site: we always return the same instance if the call site requests for a specially typed deserializer (it's always the same instance however, this is just how Java generics work)
    static <T> JsonDeserializer<ResponseWrap<T>> getResponseWrapJsonDeserializer() {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        final JsonDeserializer<ResponseWrap<T>> cast = (JsonDeserializer) responseWrapJsonDeserializer;
        return cast;
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseWrap<T> deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        // Checking if jsonElement looks like an error (I'm not sure if it's possible to check HTTP statuses delegating them to request/response converters in Retrofit)
        if ( isError(jsonElement) ) {
            final List<ErrorResponse> errorResponses = context.deserialize(jsonElement, errorResponseListType);
            return new ResponseWrap<>(null, errorResponses);
        }
        // If it does not look an error, then:
        // * resolve what's the actual T in the given ResponseWrap<T>
        // * deserialize the JSON tree as an instance of T -- it's like we're stripping the wrapper and then instantiate the wrap due to our rules
        final T response = context.deserialize(jsonElement, resolveTypeParameter0(type));
        return new ResponseWrap<>(response, null);
    }

    private static Type resolveTypeParameter0(final Type type) {
        // The given type does not have parameterization?
        if ( !(type instanceof ParameterizedType) ) {
            // Then it's raw, simply <Object> or <?>
            return Object.class;
        }
        // If it's parameterized, let's take it's first parameter as ResponseWrap is known to a have a single type parameter only
        return ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    // Some AI party here, he-he
    private static boolean isError(final JsonElement jsonElement) {
        if ( !jsonElement.isJsonArray() ) {
            return false;
        }
        final JsonArray jsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
        for ( final JsonElement innerJsonElement : jsonArray ) {
            if ( !innerJsonElement.isJsonObject() ) {
                return false;
            }
            final JsonObject innerJsonObject = innerJsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            final boolean looksLikeErrorObject = innerJsonObject.has("errorCode");
            if ( !looksLikeErrorObject ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Next, register the deserializer for your `Gson` instance:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(ResponseWrap.class, getResponseWrapJsonDeserializer())
        .create();
```

And test it with

#### success.json

```
{
    "foo": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

#### failure.json

```
[
    {"errorCode": 10001},
    {"errorCode": 10002}
]
```

```java
// It's a constant
// Also, ResponseWrap<Map<String,List<Integer>>>.class is illegal in Java
private static final Type type = new TypeToken<ResponseWrap<Map<String, List<Integer>>>>() {
}.getType();

public static void main(String... args)
        throws IOException {
    final String successJson = getPackageResourceString(Q43525433.class, "success.json");
    final String failureJson = getPackageResourceString(Q43525433.class, "failure.json");
    final ResponseWrap<Map<String, List<Integer>>> success = gson.fromJson(successJson, type);
    final ResponseWrap<Map<String, List<Integer>>> failure = gson.fromJson(failureJson, type);
    System.out.println("SUCCESS: " + success.response);
    for ( final ErrorResponse response : failure.errorResponses ) {
        System.out.println("FAILURE: " + response.errorCode);
    }
}
```

The output:

> SUCCESS: {foo=[1, 2, 3]}
>   FAILURE: 10001
>   FAILURE: 10002

And yes, don't forget to add `gson` to Retrofit using `GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)`.

Also, you might be interested in [Json response parser for Array or Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113283/json-response-parser-for-array-or-object) that describe the almost the same issue but from another perspective.